# Figure numbering mismatch in caption and in text

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, numbering, labels

I'm having a labelling conflict between figures and tables in Latex.

Document class: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vDS_jDmvIuVtHzpa_Ms5cz2VgtiWwvdv/view

Here's my current code.

```
\documentclass[sort&compress, numbers]{chart}

\usepackage[varg]{txfonts} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lipsum}


\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@captype}{figure}
\makeatother
\centering


\geometry{margin=1.5cm}

\graphicspath{{Images/}}  

\begin{document}

Table \ref{tab:histogram tab1} shows some experiments.

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
    \caption{Test \cite{Singh10}}
    \label{tab:histogram tab1}
    \begin{tblr}{|c|c|X[j,c]|X[j,c]|X[j,c]|}
    \hline
    Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.
    However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
    Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
    across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
    but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
    Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
    Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
    throughout the evening. \\
    \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{multicols}{2}
 

Figure \ref{fig:evaluation:revenue} shows some experiments.  \lipsum[2]
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}

    \subfloat[Market revenue]{%
      \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a}%
      \label{fig:evaluation:revenue}%
    }\qquad%
    \subfloat[Average price]{%
      \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-b}%
      \label{fig:evaluation:avgPrice}%
    }
    \caption{Simulation results}
  \end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

My current result for figure is not tally. Having **Figure 0(a)** instead of **Figure 1(a)** and my table result is correct. How does this happen ? It's quite weird.

[image: Current result]

Comment: Can you add a link to your documentclass? In normal classes you wouldn't be able to use caption outside of a floating environment.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I guess that's the fault of his `\newcommand{\@captype}{figure}`.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
The document class can refer from here.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vDS_jDmvIuVtHzpa_Ms5cz2VgtiWwvdv/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a better result with

```
\begin{multicols}{2}            
    Subfigure~\subref{fig:evaluation:revenue} in Figure~\ref{fig:full} shows some experiments.  \lipsum[2]
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}          
        \subfloat[Market revenue\label{fig:evaluation:revenue}]{%
            \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-a}%               
        }\qquad%
        \subfloat[Average price\label{fig:evaluation:avgPrice}]{%
            \includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-b}%           
        }
        \caption{Simulation results}\label{fig:full}%
    \end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
```

[image: a]

(1) Put labels next or inside the captions;

(2) Reference the subfigures with `\subref{<sub label>}`.

(3) To get Figure 1(a) use  `Figure~\ref{fig:full}\subref{fig:evaluation:revenue}`

Comment: Looks cool ! 
Thanks for your help